# Erro ao executar função passada via parametro no javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho essa função modalConfirmacao que estou tentando usar para diversas funções. Nela eu passo o titulo e a mensagem do modal e a função a ser executada caso o usuário clique em OK.

```
function modalConfirmacao(titulo, mensagem,funcao) {
    var htmlModal = '<div class="modal fade" id="modalDefault" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">' +
                        '<div class="modal-dialog">'+
                            '<div class="modal-content">'+
                                '<!-- Modal Header -->'+
                                '<div class="modal-header">'+
                                    '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'+
                                        titulo
                                    +'</h4>'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">'+
                                        '&times;'+
                                    '</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<!-- Modal Body -->'+
                                '<div class="modal-body">'+
                                    mensagem
                                +'</div>'+
                                '<!-- Modal Footer -->'+
                                '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                    '<button type="button" id="ok" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">'+
                                        'OK'+
                                    '</button>'+
                                    '<button type="button" id="cancelar" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">'+
                                        'Cancelar'+
                                    '</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
            $('body').append(htmlModal);
            $("#modalDefault").modal();
            $("#ok").on("click",funcao);
}
```

Para chamar a função eu faço assim no onclick do botão:

```
modalConfirmacao("Confirmar","Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto "+codigo+"?",excluirProduto);
```

A função excluirProduto tem uma chamada Ajax no php para excluir o produto.

```
function excluirProduto(codigo){
            $.post('excluirproduto.php',{codigo:codigo},function(e){
                e = $.parseJSON(e);
                if(e){
                    alert("Produto excluido");

                }else{
                    alert("Erro ao excluir produto");
                }

            });
        }
```

Meu problema é que quando clico no botão que chama a função excluirProduto  pela primeira vez ele executa a função 1 vez, da segunda vez 2 vez, da terceira vez 3 vezes e assim por diante. 
O que pode estar acontecendo?
Estou passando ou chamando a função erroneamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `on()` do jQuery acumula os manipuladores de eventos, isto é, cada vez que for chamada a `modalConfirmacao()`, ele vai ligar o manipulador de evento de novo no `click` do botão OK.

Você teria que mudar o código para realizar a ligação do evento `click` com o botão OK uma vez apenas, ou usar `off()`, para "desligar" um manipulador:

```
$("#ok").off("click").on("click", funcao);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção.
A sugestão do off funcionou perfeitamente!!!
Você sugeriu também mudar o código para fazer a ligação do evento click apenas uma vez. 
Como faria isso?

Comment: Pensando melhor, talvez não tenha jeito, mesmo.

Comment: Então dentro da função prepararModal eu teria :  $("#ok").on("click",funcao_que_manipula_ok);
E dentro da função modalConfirmacao de alguma forma fazer com que essa função prepararModal seja executada uma unica vez?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi então, toda vez que chamo a função modalConfirmacao ele estava colocando um novo evento, ai estava meio que acumulando  fazendo executar a função o numero de vezes que o botão foi clicado, mais ou menos isso?
Acho que entendi mas não consigo explicar...rsrs

Comment: Dentro de `modalConfirmacao()` pode ter uma função, por exemplo, `function estadoSetado() { return modalConf.estado; }` e pode ter duas variáveis, `var estado;` e `var modalConf = this;`. Daí, na chamada de `prepararModal(func)`, você faz `if (!estadoSetado()) { preparaModal(excluirProduto); estado = true; }`... Ficou complicado :(

Comment: Não; como o `$("#ok").on("click", funcao);` estava sendo chamado várias vezes, a cada rodada desta linha, ele adicionava de novo o `excluirProduto`. Entendeu?

Comment: Entendi,perfeito.Obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você também poderia usar algumas funções do JavaScript para executar uma função apenas uma vez, depois dê uma lida referente ao `Throttle` e `Debounce`nesse link: [Throttling e Debouncing](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf)